# How to add autocomplete to a textarea on a form?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I would like to add autocomplete functionality to a textarea form element in Drupal 8. I have a fully functioning custom textfield which has autocomplete working on the same form. I have confirmed that the [Textarea element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Textarea.php/class/Textarea/8.2.x) has the processAutocomplete function. Therefore, I'm uncertain as to why this wouldn't work.

I realize that adding an autocomplete to a textarea is a bit unorthodox, but that's not the question. I have seen this done in Drupal 8, so I know it's possible. I just don't know if they used a form to accomplish it.

I have added the appropriate code in the routing file:

```
my_module.autocomplete_name:
   path: '/my-module/test-autocomplete'
   defaults:
     _controller:'\Drupal\my_module\Controller\Controller::functionName'
     _format: json
   requirements:
     _access: 'TRUE'
```

I have also added the field appropriately on the form:

```
$form['text_area'] = [
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#title' => t('Test text area'),
  '#default_value' => $authentication_configuration->get('text_area'),
  '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'my_module.autocomplete_name',
];
```

Finally, I have the appropriate logic in the referenced controller:

```
public function testAutocomplete(request $request) {
  // Set up the array to be returned and get the user input
  $matches = array();
  $input = $request->query->get('q');
  // If there is user input
  if ($input) {
    $words = explode(' ', $input);
    foreach ($words as $word) {
      /*
       * Logic for generating an autocomplete list of matches
       */
    }
  }
  return new JsonResponse($matches);
}
```

Comment: Another good blog article on that issue: https://www.qed42.com/blog/autocomplete-drupal-8 – seems a bit as if this was your starting point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Textareas don't support autocomplete out of the box, you have to get a bit creative to make it work.

First you'll need to override the `attach` method of the autocomplete behaviour; add a library with a JS file containing this:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.autocomplete.attach = function attach(context) {
    var $autocomplete = $(context).find('input.form-autocomplete,textarea.form-autocomplete').once('autocomplete');
    if ($autocomplete.length) {
      var blacklist = $autocomplete.attr('data-autocomplete-first-character-blacklist');
      $.extend(Drupal.autocomplete.options, {
        firstCharacterBlacklist: blacklist || ''
      });

      $autocomplete.autocomplete(Drupal.autocomplete.options).each(function () {
        $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = Drupal.autocomplete.options.renderItem;
      });

      $autocomplete.on('compositionstart.autocomplete', function () {
        Drupal.autocomplete.options.isComposing = true;
      });
      $autocomplete.on('compositionend.autocomplete', function () {
        Drupal.autocomplete.options.isComposing = false;
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

The function is a straight copy of the core `attach` method, with the `textarea` added to the selectors, and a few references altered.

Then you'll need to add the autocomplete process method to the form element (it's not there by default), and also reference your library:

```
use Drupal\Core\Render\Element\Textarea;

...

$form['text_area'] = [
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#title' => t('Test text area'),
  '#default_value' => $authentication_configuration->get('text_area'),
  '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'my_module.autocomplete_name',
  '#process' => [
    [Textarea::class, 'processAutocomplete'],
  ],
  '#attached' => [
    'library' => [
      'mymodule/autocomplete'
    ],
  ],
];
```

Clear the cache and you should see the results immediately.

Comment: It worked! For those who may want to do this, be sure to include the use statement above. If you don't, it will not render a textarea.